# Razor view engine automatically applying quotes?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm fairly used to razor now, but I can't understand why the following syntax is correct?

```
<li @(active ? "class=active" : "")>
   @Html.ActionLink(item.Text, item.TargetAction, Model.Controller)
</li>
```

As you can see I'm conditionally applying a class (and I've written it this way so the class tag is not generated if the bool active == false).

What I can't understand is why this then generates the correct quotes to give:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
   <a href="/">Home</a>
</li>
```

Somehow it is magically sorting out the quoting, but I can't find any reference in the articles on razor to suggest this is expected, so I'm wondering if it is relying on broken behaviour. If I add single or double quotes into the string around the word 'active', as you would expect to if cranking out html, I end up with:

```
<li class="'active'">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
</li>
```

or

```
<li class=&quot;active&quot;>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
</li>
```

Why does it work this way, and is my code correct (as opposed to simply functioning)?

Comment: I can vouche that razor is automatically adding quotes to 'class='. Just spent an hour trying to figure out why &#34; was coming out as "" turns out razor is parsing the html code then adding a second double quote. Doing this stuff automatically is NOT helpful at all.

Answer (score 18):

Just come across this so thought would answer - SLaks looks right with Html.Raw, but the OP is also correct in that the second method doesn't look to work - the "s get encoded.

My solution was:

```
<li@(active ? Html.Raw(" class=\"active\"") : null)>
```

Comment: thanks, adding null instead of "" solved it for me. presumably the problem is something to do with the conversion to string (as opposed to htmlstring with the null).

Comment: thanks just came across with with bootstrapper where there classes use space to define them aka class="panel panel-primary" ended up using the above... full working example <div @(item.Success ? Html.Raw(" class=\"panel panel-success\"") : Html.Raw(" class=\"panel panel-warning\""))>

Comment: This doesn't work. The output of `Html.Raw` is `IHtmlString` not `string`, so you need to `.ToString()` it. And the output is still `&quot;` . For me a solution is to not put quote `<li@(active ? " class=active" : null)>` . Browsers renders this well.

Comment: Unfortunately, browsers tend to convert &quot; to " as you can see by inspecting with the dev tools in, say, Chrome,  however, Google's search spider does NOT. (making this a true bug in Razor by doing this automatically - it does not output " but outputs &quot; (since browsers convert this to a quote, you won't think anything is wrong!)

Answer (score 14):

Razor automatically HTML-escapes all code output.
You can prevent this by writing `@Html.Raw(...)`

Alternatively, you can put the quotes in the literal text:

```
<li class="@(active ? "active" : "")>
```

Your example works because you don't actually have any quotes.
The generated HTML source reads `<li class=active>`.

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't actually read as you say. It is automatically putting the quotes around "active", I've checked view source in two different browsers. This is the nub of my question. Where does it say in any docs that this is expected behaviour?

Comment: bizarre I've checked a few times and with differing browsers. I'm using MVC3 here. Will check again.

Comment: Try Fiddler.  Are you using any open-source libraries that might affect output?

Comment: Maybe simply the browser inspector is adding quotes? I think when using EPiServer, something in it adds quotes (and unwraps block elements wrappen in inline elements, BTW)

Comment: ur example is missing a quote `<li class="@(active ? "active" : "")>` should be `<li class="@(active ? "active" : "")>"` and what is being discusses here is that ur u put this the result would be `<li class=""active"">` if true, but what would it be if its were `<li @somevalue >` see the missing quotes, its adding them in, now if they in the string then they get added twice. hence this discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this bizarre behavior as well.  Logically the following should work.

```
@(Model.IsTablet ? "data-options='is_hover: false'" : "")
```

but is rendered as

```
data-options="'is_hover:" false&#39;=""
```

As Dan states this works correctly

```
@(Model.IsTablet ? "data-options=is_hover:false" : "")
```

rendering as the first example should.

```
data-options="is_hover:false"
```

but if you add a space in the attribute it breaks whatever weird stuff asp.net 4.0 is doing and it thinks your attribute ends at the space.

And this does not constitute html escaping as what is valid html syntax doesn't work and the whole point of razor is that the razor syntax should work with valid html not break it.