# Razor escaping single quotes in data attributes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, quotes

I'm trying to get Razor to display a dropdown list with data_bind attibutes for knockout

so starting with

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Form.selectedItem, Model.empty, new
               {
                    @class = "multiselected" 

               })
```

I've tried multiple things to get the data added using this with a dictionary object

```
 { "data_bind" , MvcHtmlString.Create("options: optionSelected, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'") }
```

This

```
 "data_bind" = MvcHtmlString.Create("options: optionSelected, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'") 

 "data_bind" = Html.Raw("options: optionSelected, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'") 

"data_bind" = Html.Raw(MvcHtmlString.Create("options: optionSelected, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"))
```

Whatever I try the single quotes get changed to `&#39;`. What gives?

**Edit**

Turns out that knockout doesn't mind the quotes and can still bind.
The other questions don't relate to knockout and data attributes. In list/input elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731421/output-single-quotes-in-razor-generated-javascript-string
Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9234496/392102

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor view engine automatically applying quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234467/razor-view-engine-automatically-applying-quotes)

Comment: Yeah, I've looked through them and as you can see I've tried the solutions but to no avail. Thanks for having a look though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the single quotes are escaped in the html, this won't affect the binding, which will see them correctly as single quotes.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  options: [{ name: 'first one', id: '1' },
            { name: 'second one', id: '2' }, 
            { name: 'third one', id: '3' }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: options, optionsText: &#39;name&#39;, optionsValue: &#39;id&#39;, optionsCaption: &#39;Choose...&#39;">
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oxtupfx8/

Comment: Ah, intresting - I'll give it a go

Comment: For the win. Arg just starting with Knockout/c# so cutting myself a break. It can be a bit tricky to debug the knockout so I just presumed it was the quotes. Thanks for your help.