# Adding element attribute in view based on razor variable

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that has a list and I want to add a class to a specific list item depending on a variable in the view model.

```
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

The variable could be anything.  Currently it is an integer.  Below is what I have now, but I don't think this is the cleanest way to do this.

```
string[] listClasses = new string[3];
int? selectedListElement= (int?)ViewData["SelectedListElement"];
if(tabNumber.HasValue)
{
    tabClasses[tabNumber.Value] = "selected";
}
<li class="@listClasses[0]">List Item 1</li>
<li class="@listClasses[1]">List Item 2</li>
<li class="@listClasses[2]">List Item 3</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put the class name into your view model and use conditional attributes

[Conditional HTML Attributes using Razor MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061647/conditional-html-attributes-using-razor-mvc3)

Comment: So you are saying add 3 variables to my view model and set them to either null or "selected",  then in the view do <li class="@listItem1Class">List Item 1</li>?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Thanks.  It removed any logic in the view.  Then on the viewModel I just set ViewData["list" + selected + "class"] = "selected"  Then in the view I set each list to have a class attribute class="@ViewData["list1class"]", etc.  If the viewdata is null conditional attributes save me.  Thanks