# Conditional element class outputs "class"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am iterating round a model's comments (a collection of `Comment` objects), and need to style them based on whether the property `Private` is `true` or `false`.

I tried to add a class based on a property like this:

```
<div class="contact-card comment_p_@(comment.Private)">
```

But the generated html keeps giving me

```
<div class="contact-card comment_p_class">
```

Even though I have directly below this element

```
<p>@comment.Private</p>
```

which outputs `<p>True</p>` or `<p>False</p>` as appropriate.

Here is the full loop:

```
@foreach (var comment in comments)
{
    <div class="contact-card comment_p_@comment.Private">
        <strong>@comment.UserName</strong>
        <p>@comment.Private</p>
        <strong class="pull-right">@comment.DateTime</strong>
        <p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">@comment.Content</p>
    </div>
}
```

And output of one iteration:

```
<div class="contact-card comment_p_class">
    <strong>skotze</strong>
    <p>True</p>
    <strong class="pull-right">29/11/2017 03:18:12</strong>
    <p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">asda123</p>
</div>
```

I also tried

```
<div class="contact-card comment_p_@comment.Private">
<div class="@comment.Private">
<div class="comment-@comment.Private">
```

But I always get the same results...when I try to set the class using the property, the output html changes it to just `class`, even though I am able to print the true value when its just in a `<p>`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain the behavior, there are 2 types of 'conditional attributes' in razor-2.

For attributes that expect a `string` value, for example `class="someValue"`, then when you use

```
@{
    string classname = "myclass";
    string noclass = null;
}
<div class="@classname">xx</div>
<div class="@noclass">xx</div>
```

Then the output will be

```
<div class="myclass">xx</div>
<div>xx</div>
```

When the value of the property is null, it omits the attribute, otherwise it generates the attribute with the value of the property.

The other type is used for `boolean` attributes, such as generating a `checked="checked"` attribute.

When you use

```
@{
    bool checked = true;
    bool notchecked = false;
}
<input type="checkbox" checked="@checked" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="@notchecked" />
```

Then the output will be

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@checked" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

When the value of the property is `true`, it adds the attribute with the same value as the name of the attribute - i.e. `checked="checked"` and when the value is `false` it omits the attribute.

In your case, the property is a `bool` with a value of `true` so the razor engine generates the value as the same name as the attribute - i.e. `"class"` and appends it to the existing value and the result is

```
<div class="contact-card comment_p_class">
```

Had the value of the property been `false` it would have generated just

```
<div class="contact-card comment_p_">
```

As noted in your self answer, it is necessary to use

```
<div class="contact-card @(comment.Private ? "comment-priv" : "comment-pub" )">
```

or similar conditional code to generate the `class` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, yes I did notice that a False value generated `comment_p_` so that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by copying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700741/how-to-add-a-second-css-class-with-a-conditional-value-in-razor-mvc-4):

```
<div class="contact-card @(@comment.Private ? "comment-priv" : "comment-pub" )">
```

But accoring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061647/conditional-html-attributes-using-razor-mvc3), my original attempt should work.

If anyone can explain why it behaves like that I will accept their answer.

Comment: I think your misunderstanding how Razor-2 conditional attributes work (the 2nd link you gave as not related to your situation)