# Is there a way to terminate MVC Razor @: line?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, razor, razorengine

Consider this example:

```
<input type="checkbox" @if (flag) { @: checked } />
```

The problem is that the `} />` is conceived by the Razor engine as part of the output string.

I've tried to use parenthesis but no luck.

Is there a way to terminate the `@:` operator in same line, or I'll have to split it to other line / use ternary operator?

### Update

A very common use-case of my request can be adding a class if a value is true:

```
<div class='container @(active ? "active")'/>
```

So if the `:` of the ternary operator isn't present, it treats it treats it as a unary `if` operator, but that's just a wish...

[Here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7288182-add-unary-ternary-operator)'s my suggestion on C# UserVoice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ternary operator in razor (specifically on HTML attributes)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091831/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-razor-specifically-on-html-attributes)

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Nope. Looks like you haven't even bothered reading my post. As I stated in my post, I know about the ternary operator and how to use it but I do NOT prefer to use it, I only want to emit a string if flag is true, but I want to do nothing if it's not.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox"  checked="@flag" />` could work (http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/ )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov haha! that's awesome. Why not post as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For single attribute you can use `@value` syntax, that also have special case for checkbox (see [Razor quick reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) ):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@flag" />
```

You also can use `<text>` syntax that provides explicit (instead of "up to end of the line") closing tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" @if (flag) { <text>checked</text> } />
```